# first EOF not working?

Tags: command-line

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and when I run something in terminal like `md5sum` it waits for my input and I enter something like `Hello` but when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it does not terminate and I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> for the second time to terminate that! why?

Comment: does it work if you press enter first (finish with a newline)?

Comment: Are you using the terminal locally? I experienced the same behavior in PuTTY some time ago.

Comment: @Zanna,  no it does not, I have to press `^D` twice.

Comment: @Melebius, yes I'm using locally.

Comment: @MaskedMan, same behavior here,  it ends either with two `^D` or `enter` then `^D`

Comment: @user.dz, I'm asking why the first `^D` is not interpreted `EOF` when is not on it's own line!

Comment: Exactly same question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177651/ctrld-for-ending-terminal-line-input

Comment: @user.dz, I guessed that myself but thanks, I'm not sure about it. :)

Comment: @Zanna, Thank you for remind, I copied the accepted answer from UL as wiki.

Answer (score 1):

> In Unix, most objects you can read and write - ordinary files, pipes,
>   terminals, raw disk drives - are all made to resemble files.
>
> A program like `cat` reads from its standard input like this:
>
> ```
> n = read(0, buffer, 512);
> ```
>
> which asks for 512 bytes. `n` is the number of bytes actually read, or
>   -1 if there's an error.
>
> If you did this repeatedly with an ordinary file, you'd get a bunch of
>   512-byte reads, then a somewhat shorter read at the tail end of the
>   file, then 0 if you tried to read past the end of the file. So, `cat`
>   will run until `n` is <= 0.
>
> Reading from a terminal is slightly different. After you type in a
>   line, terminated by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, `read` returns just that
>   line.
>
> There are a few special characters you can type. One is
>   <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>. When you type this, the operating system sends all
>   of the current line that you've typed (but not the <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>
>   itself) to the program doing the read. And here's the serendipitous
>   thing: if <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> is the first character on the line, the
>   program is sent a line of length 0 - just like the program would see
>   if it just got to the end of an ordinary file. `cat` *doesn't need to
>   do anything differently*, whether it's reading from an ordinary file
>   or a terminal.
>
> Another special character is <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>. When you type it,
>   anywhere in a line, the operating system discards whatever you've
>   typed up until that point and sends a SIGTSTP signal to the program,
>   which normally stops (pauses) it and returns control to the shell.
>
> So in your example
>
> ```
> $ cat > file.txt
> pa bam pshhh<Ctrl+Z>
> [2]+  Stopped         cat > file.txt
> ```
>
> you typed some characters that were discarded, then `cat` was stopped
>   without having written anything to its output file.
>
> ```
> $ cat > file.txt
> pa bam pshhh
> <Ctrl+Z>
> [2]+  Stopped         cat > file.txt
> ```
>
> you typed in one line, which `cat` read and wrote to its output file,
>   and then the <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> stopped `cat`.

<sup>**Source:** [Ctrl+D for ending terminal line input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177661/12209) answer by 
[Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49439/mark-plotnick)</sup>